# Visual Studio doesn't detect android device, but Android Device monitor detects the device

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

[Visual Studio doesn't detect android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pqJ7.png) but [Android Device monitor detects the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CRZR.png). How to fix android device detection in Visual Studio?

Comment: What is your Visual studio version? Maybe you can try to update to the latest version to see whether there is still having problem.

Comment: Visual studio 2019 Community. I reinstalled it, but it didn't help.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 community version? for example, my visual studio version is Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 Version 16.9.4, maybe you can take a look [Android Emulator Setup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/) firstly.

Comment: I have the same issue - any update on this. I am using Visual Studio 2022 community edition